# Docker TYPO3 Directory / is not writable

Tags: php, apache, docker, typo3

I created my own docker environment for TYPO3. It also starts. The problem is I can't install TYPO3 because I don't grant write rights to the folders.
`ERROR:' Path /var/www/html exists, but no file underneath it can be created.'`
[image]

Here is my dockerfile  & docker-compose.yml for apache and PHP Setup:

Any Solutions how I can fix this issue?

```html
FROM php:7.0-apache

# PHP Extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql


# Composer
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
RUN php composer-setup.php
RUN php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer


ADD vhost-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

# Open Ports
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

```html
  app:
    build:
      context: ./Docker/apache
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: apache
    ports:
        - "8090:80"
        - "443:443"
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html
    environment:
        - API_TOKEN=xxxx
```

Comment: On a linux host system?

Comment: Is it the same problem if you add another path to your host? maybe /home/xxx/projects or so?

Comment: It could be that the server in your docker runs with www-data and this user has not writing permissions to your local. But I'm not sure.

Comment: I think this could be the way to go. Unfortunately I've no time to test it. https://denibertovic.com/posts/handling-permissions-with-docker-volumes/

Comment: @Falk yeah the APACHE_RUN_USER run with www-data any solutions how can i grant them the right rights?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did anybody has a solution?

Comment: I've also got this issue. Connecting to bash and change the permissions in the running container works for me but is only a temporary fix.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. You just need to create the `typo3conf/ext/` folder during build process.

I've had the same problem, because the snippet I've downloaded just creates the typo3conf folder. So, when `chown -R www-data. .` is performed, the ext folder does not exist. And when you then mount volumes inside the ext folder, the folder got root permissions.

So, just create not only the **typo3conf/**, but also the **ext/** folder inside, fixed the issue for me.